# метод find выводит undefined

Tags: javascript

```
Clothes.prototype.getReviewByID = function(key){

  this.reviews.find(function(element){
    if(element.ID === key){
      return element;
    }
  })
};
```

Есть метод который находит объект по значению его свойства(ID) и возвращает объект где найдено совпадение. Find выводит undefined, а вот через цикл for(внизу) всё работает. Почему не работает find ??

```
Clothes.prototype.getReviewByID = function(key){
 for(var i = 0; i < this.reviews.length; i++) {
   if(this.reviews[i].ID === key){
     return this.reviews[i];
   }
 }
};
```

Comment: неверно используется метод `find`. кроме того, функция getReviewById ничего не возвращает

Comment: @Grundy а почему неверно ?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_find.asp

Comment: @Igor можно пожалуйста конкретней в чем я ошибся  ?

Comment: Вы прочитали статью по ссылке? Пример попробовали?

Comment: функция передаваемая в find должна возвращать true если  элемент подходит и false в противном случае

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно возвращать значение сравнения, а не элемент.

[Доцументация](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Правильный вариант:

```
Clothes.prototype.getReviewByID = function(key) {
  this.reviews.find(function(element) {
    return element.ID === key;
  });
};
```